# How to update a thumbnail?

Tags: google-drive-api

The new thumbnail feature works great when inserting a new file.
Is there a way to update the thumbnail for an existing file?
I did not manage to update the thumbnail (in Java) using the files().patch() or files().update() methods.
I don't get any error message, but the thumbnail in Google Drive is just not changing when uploading a new thumbnail.

```
File file = drive.files().get(fileId).execute();
String encodedImage = Base64.encodeBase64URLSafeString(imageData);
Thumbnail thumbnail = new Thumbnail();
thumbnail.setImage(encodedImage);
thumbnail.setMimeType("image/png");
file.setThumbnail(thumbnail);
drive.files().update(fileId, file).execute();
```

Update:
As I am using exactly the same code for inserting a file with thumbnail (which works) and updating the file as shown in the code snippet above (which will not update the thumbnail) it may make sense that you use my app to perform both operations.

```
Login to www.ultradox.com
Copy one of the examples. 
This will create a new file on your Google Drive with the correct thumbnail 
(as it triggers the insert file method with thumbnail).
Click on the "Customize" button
Scroll down and click on the thumbnail image to upload a new thumbnail
= Thumbnail not changed, but update should be triggered. 
So probably something shows up in your logs?
```

Comment: Can you show your code and the error you get?

Comment: The code seems correct, are you sure the old thumbnail is not simply being cached?

Comment: Do you mean cached in Google Drive? I've reloaded the Drive page several times (shift+reload) without any effect. If you want you can try yourself at www.ultradox.com

Comment: No, I thought cached on the client side. I'll investigate whether there's a delay before updated thumbnails are shown.

Comment: Any news? I can provide more info if needed.

Comment: Yes please, more info would be great.

Comment: As I am using exactly the same code for inserting a file with thumbnail (which works) and updating the file as shown in the code snippet above (which will not update the thumbnail) it may make sense that you use my app to perform both operations.
    - Login to www.ultradox.com
    - Copy one of the examples. This will create a new file on your Google Drive with the correct thumbnail (as it triggers the insert file method with thumbnail).

Comment: This looks like a bug, so thanks for the report. I have reproduced it, and will keep you up-to-date on a fix.

Comment: I updated the answer, seems it is intended behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current behavior is that updates to metadata alone do not allow a change in the thumbnail. So changes to the metadata alone do not take the thumbnail change. I am not sure this is the best behavior, and we will try to improve it to:

1. Allow the thumbnail update
2. Report an error rather than appearing to succeed

Comment: Can I update a thumbnail when uploading some dummy content? Or is there a proposed workaround?

Comment: Yes, dummy content, or re-upload the same content again?

Comment: Im also interested in updating only thumbnail and get link to it.

Comment: How can i update thumbnail for my big TIF file that already on GD, but without preview?